# Getting error "A reg is not legal lvalue in this context"

Tags: verilog, testbench

I am trying to create a blockwave in SimVision, but I am struggling with the top-level module. I keep getting the same error and can't figure out the solution. The error is:

> A reg is not legal lvalue in this context

This is the blockwave module:

```
    `timescale 1ns/1ps

   module square_wave(clk,rst,dac_out);
   input clk; // assuming 1 MHz
   input rst;
   output reg dac_out;
   reg [11:0]  counter; // 12-bit for numbers up to 3999

   always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        if (rst == 1'b1  ||  counter == 12'd3999) // period, count from 0 to n-1
          counter <= 0;
        else
          counter <= counter + 1'b1;

        // synchronous output without glitches
        if (rst == 1'b0  &&  counter < 12'd2000) // duty cycle, m cycles high
          dac_out = 1'b1;
        else
          dac_out = 1'b0;
    end
endmodule // square_wave
```

This code is fairy solid normally, but I'm having trouble in the `toplevel` module.

```
    `timescale 1ns/1ps

module toplevel ();

    reg clk = 1'b1;
    reg rst = 1'b1;
    reg dac_out = 1'b1;

    wire [11:0]  counter;

    // Clk gen (fclk = 100MHz)
    always
    #5 clk = ~clk;

    // Reset and enable
    initial begin
        #5 rst = 1'b0;
        #15 rst = 1'b1;
    end
    // Counter instance 
    square_wave inst_counter (
        .clk        (clk),
        .rst        (rst),
        .dac_out    (dac_out)      // Error on this line
        );
            
endmodule
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the testbench, you are driving the `dac_out` signal with multiple drivers.  You should only drive it from the `square_wave` instance.  There is no need to initialize it to 1 when you declare it.  Also, declare the signal using `wire` instead of `reg`:

Change:

```
reg dac_out = 1'b1;
```

to:

```
wire dac_out;
```

Note: I did not get the exact error message you got with my simulators.  This change eliminates all compile errors on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Gnvg).  Sometimes different simulators give you more helpful error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am still getting the same error. I am new to verilog simvision combination.

Comment: @samverachten: You're welcome.  I updated my answer with a link to the fixed code.  You can see that it compiles without any errors there on multiple simulators.  If you are still not able to reproduce my results, I suggest you start over.  Copy and paste the code from EDA Playground into your clean code editor, then try again.